# c# - simplest way to sort a field from an array loaded from JSON

Tags: c#, sorting

What's the simplest way to sort a field from an array loaded from JSON.I've found some things on Anonymous Functions but I'd like to know if theres a more basic way.

```
 static void SortItems(Items[] items)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Choose field to sort (Name, Weapon, Strength)");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Items[] sortedItem;
        if (userInput.ToLower() == "name")
        {
            string[] name = items.Select( m => m.Name).ToArray();    

        }

        else if (userInput.ToLower() ==  "weapon")
        {
            string[] weapon = items.Select(m => m.EquippedWeapon.Name).ToArray();

        }
        else if (userInput.ToLower() == "strength")
        {
            int[] totalStrength = items.Select(m => m.GetStrength()).ToArray();
        }

         sortedItems = Sorts.Sort(items, userInput);

        foreach (Items c in sortedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} - Weapon: {1} - Total strength: {2}", c.Name, c.Weapon.Name,  c.strength().ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Linq extensions, you could do something more like this

```
static void SortItems(Items[] items)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Choose field to sort (Name, Weapon, Strength)");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput))
    {
        Items[] sortedItems;
        switch (userInput.Trim().ToLower())
        {
            case ("name"):
                sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
                break;
            case ("weapon"):
                sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Weapon).ToArray();
                break;
            case ("strength"):
                sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Strength).ToArray();
                break;
            default:
                //return whatever for default
                sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
                break;
        }

        foreach (Items c in sortedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} - Weapon: {1} - Total strength: {2}", c.Name, c.Weapon.Name,
                c.strength().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to create a separate method for the values to pass? I keep getting an exception : "Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Comment: I don't understand your cquestion, I cant see from the code above why you would get that exception. Please add further information, or post the exact code you are using now.